# Serverless Websocket service deploy fails with Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException

Tags: websocket, serverless-framework, serverless, aws-serverless

Using Serverless Framework I have build a websocket service.

On serverless deploy I am getting: An error occurred: WebsocketsDeployment1605517494880 - A route target (typically an Integration) must be defined for route X with key $default (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException; Request ID: Y; Proxy: null).

Attempt to fix this I added:

```
default:

  handler: handler.defaultMessage

  events:

    - websocket: $default
```

to the serverless.yaml file, and now I am getting: An error occurred: SdefaultWebsocketsRoute - Route with key $default already exists for this API (Service: AmazonApiGatewayV2; Status Code: 409; Error Code: ConflictException; Request ID: X; Proxy: null).

I am not sure what the problem is, how do I fix this?